# How web browsers and WebCrypto API protects secrets

Tags: encryption, keys, secure-storage, tpm

I tried to search and take a look at a way to securely generate or import secret keys on client-side. First I tried to see if it is possible to take advantage of TPM in Windows but as far as I understood it is not possible to use it. So as far as I got the correct way to deal with encryption keys was using Web Crypto API. I figured out that it uses IndexedDB to store the keys. I truly want to know how these keys are being protected from getting extracted if imported. I know that you need to set extractable property of the Key to false but does it take advantage of TPM or any hardware module to protect keys or just software based protection? BTW I read how KeyStore protects keys so I wonder if for web applications we have such an alternative.